# Not find the item in dataframe of python

Tags: python, dataframe

There is the structure of table in Python dataframe:

```
University_Name         Country
Princeton University    United States
Oxford                  United kingdom
UBC                     Canada
```

I hope to get the country by the university's name.For example, if I choose UBC and I will get Canada.

I use dataframe to get the country's name. Codes are as below:

```
self.df[self.df['University_name'] == 'UBC', 'Country']
```

However, I got the error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know any reason to use `self` here. The following should work fine:

```
df.loc[(df['University_Name'] == 'UBC'), 'County']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  
countries=df[df['university']=="UBC"]["country"]
print(countries)
```